# Cache Tag Helper (vary by cookie) not working

Tags: asp.net-core

I try to cache content vary by cookie value. This is Razor code:

```
<cache vary-by-cookie="temp">
    @DateTime.UtcNow
</cache>
```

And this is temp testing cookie:
[image]

I do not any changes in cookie file but content still refreshes just about every 30 seconds.
It doesn't work with real cookies too, temp cookie is just for clarity. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official documentation:

> Additional requests show the cached value until the cache expires (default 20 minutes) or until the cached date is evicted from the cache.

But in my case default cache time for tag helper is about 30 seconds and i don't know where to change this behavior. I tested cache tag helper even in a brand new ASP.NET Core MVC template (locally and on production server). Result is the same.

To make it working i explicitly set expiration time beside "vary-by-*" parameter, like so:

```
<cache vary-by-cookie="temp" expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromDays(1)">
    <h1>@DateTime.UtcNow</h1>
</cache>
```

From now cache expires next day by default or if specified cookie changes.